# can I query across multiple servers but only include certain databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 SQL servers that I want to query against but I want to only query against certain databases. Is this something that is possible? I have them set up as registered servers and I can query system type queries across them however, if I wish to query something like

```
SELECT * FROM SJOB
```

I cannot because not every database has that table so it fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could query the `sys.tables` view to check if the table exists:

```
if exists(select * from sys.tables where type = 'U' and name = 'SJOB')
select * from SJOB
```

To use that on the registered servers group, you need to also write a `select` query for the servers where the table doesn't exists. The schema needs to match but your can use `top 0` to not return any records. You need to specify all the columns though and the dummy values need to match the types of columns:

```
if exists(select * from sys.tables where type = 'U' and name = 'SJOB')
    select * from SJOB
else
    select top 0 1 as col1name, '' as col2name
```

Comment: when I run this I just get "Command(s) completed successfully. (3 servers)". It's not returning any value.

Comment: How exactly do you run it accross the servers? There's nothing in your code to suggest that...

Comment: I have the 3 servers set up as registered servers in management studio.

Comment: OK. But how do you run it? `select * from SJOB` will run it from the current database only.

Comment: registered servers are a group that you create that will accept a sql query and run it against all of the servers in the group. I run backup queries against all 6 of my servers like this daily. The problem that I'm running into is I want to run the query like I said but not all of the db's have the table so the query fails.

Comment: Sorry, I get what you mean now. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help. i tried what you said and it still only returns the number of records instead of returning the actual query.

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me on a group of servers. If you run that on individual servers, does it work?

Comment: on a single instance it works but on a group i get this...(848 row(s) affected) instead of the expected query results. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm really not sure. It works for me in my test but it's hard for me to reproduce your case precisely.